# How to make Glide use previously downloaded image as placeholder

Tags: android, android-glide

Is it possible to show previously downloaded image in Glide as placeholder while downloading new image.

Like I have an image loaded in imageview using glide. Now the imageurl is changed, so while loading this new image is it possible to keep displaying the old image (might be from cache).

What I want is while the new image is being loaded from the URL, is it possible to keep the current image as placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to this in the discussion here - https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/527#issuecomment-148840717.

Intuitively I also thought of using `placeholder()`, but the problem is that as soon as you load the second image, you loose the reference to the first one. You can still reference it but it is not safe as it may be reused by Glide or recycled.

The proposed solution from the discussion is to use `thumbnail()` and load the first image again. The load will return the first image immediately from the memory cache and it will look as if the image did not change until the second image is loaded:

```
String currentImageUrl = ...;
String newImageUrl = ...;

Glide.with(this)
    .load(newImageUrl)
    .thumbnail(Glide.with(this)
        .load(currentImageUrl)
        .fitCenter()
    )
    .fitCenter()
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks for linking the github issue here. It does look like a good solution, though I might probably won't get the time to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Glide have a capability of getting the bitmap of the image from that url, so just get it and then save it to a desired storage into your phone, and after that in your .placeholder() just use that bitmap when you are trying to get another image , take a look at this snippet

```
/** Download the image using Glide **/

Bitmap theBitmap = null;
theBitmap = Glide.
    with(YourActivity.this).
    asBitmap().
    load("Url of your image").
    into(-1, -1).
    get(); //with this we get the bitmap of that url

   saveToInternalStorage(theBitmap, getApplicationContext(), "your preferred image name");

/** Save it on your device **/

public String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, Context context, String name){


        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
        // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir

        String name_="foldername"; //Folder name in device android/data/
        File directory = cw.getDir(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Create imageDir
        File mypath=new File(directory,name_);

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {

            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

            // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("absolutepath ", directory.getAbsolutePath());
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }

/** Method to retrieve image from your device **/

public Bitmap loadImageFromStorage(String path, String name)
    {
        Bitmap b;
        String name_= name; //your folderName
        try {
            File f=new File(path, name_);
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            return b;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }




/** Retrieve your image from device and set to imageview **/
//Provide your image path and name of the image your previously used.

Bitmap b= loadImageFromStorage(String path, String name)
ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_image_id);
img.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: in loadImageFromStorage method second parameter i.e. String name is not used?

Comment: edited the answer, check it out, i had a typo there, but you get the idea ? The most important part is getting the image bitmap with the first 7  lines of code, then save it into storage and retrieve it is not too difficult and there is plenty of posts on how to store a bitmap into internal memory and retrieve it, then just place that image into your placeholder before loading the new one :)